# Input form overrides padding?

Tags: html, css

I got an input form that is supposed to be 100% wide inside my .content class and have 20px padding inside that class and 8px padding to the left inside of that input form. The problem is that the left padding inside the input form overrides the padding inside the .content class to the right.

JS: http://jsfiddle.net/8AsxX/1/

CSS:

```
.content {
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 20px;!important
 }
input.text.big {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px #cccccc;
    padding-left: 8px;
    color: #333;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <input class="text big" name="url" type="url" placeholder="Example: http://www.facebook.com/FANPAGE-URL" required="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole `width` is calculated like `100% + 8px` for the input element, so it is overlapping parent div with `padding:20px`. You can fix it using [**calc**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) for the `input` :

```
width: calc(100% - 8px);
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/8AsxX/2/)

Comment: Perfect, I didn't know about the calc option, thanks for the help! I will mark this in 2 min when I am allowed to.

Answer (score 1):

Box sizing should do the trick.

```
.content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the behaviour is *by design*. You can compensate for it by increasing the right-padding of the container:

```
.content {
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 20px 28px 20px 20px;
 }
```